# Pandora Desktop, opening browser links

Tags: windows-7, pandora

Pandora desktop runs on Adobe Air.

Everytime I click a UI button (not browser link) for example 'Station' or 'Play' firefox opens Pandora in the browser.

Is this a Pandora Issue, Windows Setting Issue, or is anyone else seeing this?

Comment: This happens to me at work all the time and drives me nuts

Comment: Me too I'm going crazy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the Pandora One desktop client or the Beta Pandora Desktop client?  I know that the beta client has this issue.  According to this [blog post](http://blog.pandora.com/pandora/archives/2008/06/from_the_lab_pa.html) the [beta client](http://pandora.com/desktop) is no longer supported and this is one of the side effects.  You will have to upgrade to a Pandora One account to get a desktop client that behaves properly.

Answer (score 0):

Granted I am not using Windows 7 (Still on XP here at work), but I have never experienced this issue before. I've had Pandora desktop for a few days now and I have never had any weird bugs as of yet.